# Generate inline class for method call parameter in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, inline-code

When calling a method that expects an implementation of a specific class, how can I make eclipse write this boring piece of code for me?

In the following example, only the first line needs to be writen by a human:

```
o.call(
new MyFunction<List<String>>()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void call(List<String> lst) throws Exception {
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type `o.call(new MyF` then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and Eclipse should offer to complete the anonymous class skeleton for you. You might not even need the `new MyF` part, depending on how unambiguous the context is.